# Shared 'local' Database for WinRT metro apps

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a winRT app in c#, and need a very small database to facilitate information transfer between apps. There will be a handful (<10) Windows tablets on which users will do a quiz, after which the results will be uploaded to the shared DB so that an overall leaderboard can be compiled.

I've been using SQLite during development, and it works great. I would like to copy this SQLite database to a shared location, so that all the tablets will have access to it, and write their results to it. I can then write an additional 'admin' application (situated on a laptop), to query this central database and compile the leaderboard, which can then be shown.

I've been struggling in trying to find a location for this shared SQLite database. I've created a Homegroup and copied the DB to the Homegroup folder, but keep getting a 'CannotOpen' error when trying to open the SQLite connection in my app.

How can I fix the 'CannotOpen' SQLite error, and is this the best way of doing it? I don't want to include an internet dependency, as there are connectivity issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a shared location is not possible in Windows Store apps as they are sand-boxed.